# Embedding Python 3.3 in a C++ program while only able to read one line at a time from input

Tags: c++, python, boost-python, python-c-api, python-embedding

I am currently working on adding embedded Python support (and yes, extending is not an option) to a large program as part of my summer internship. Ideally, I can keep the Python support within a single .DLL, which currently contains the program's in-house scripting language and is the easiest place to integrate said language and Python.

However, due to the program's API, I only have a single input function to use. This function's return value is a single line from the current input, which could be the console or a file. The input interface cannot (within the .DLL) be converted into a stream object, buffer, or FILE pointer.

My current test code (written outside of the program, using std::string, istream, and getline to ape the restriction) is

```
// start python
Py_Initialize();

try
{
   cout << "Python " << Py_GetVersion() << endl;
   string block;
   bool in_block = false;
   while ( !cin.eof() )
   {
      string str;
      cout << (in_block ? "... " : ">>> "); // prompt string
      getline(cin,str);

      if ( in_block ) // if in an indented block
      {
         if ( str.front() != ' ' && str.front() != '\t' ) // if ending the indented block
         {
            PyRun_SimpleString(block.c_str());  // run Python code contained in block string
            block.clear();                      // clear string for next block
            in_block = false;                   // no longer in block
         }
         else // a component of an indented block
         {
            block += (str+'\n'); // append input to block string
            continue;            // do not pass block exit code, do not collect two hundred dollars
         }
      }

      // either not in an indented block, or having just come out of one
      if ( str.back() == ':' ) // if colon, start new indented block
      {
         block = (str+'\n');
         in_block = true;
         continue;
      }
      else { PyRun_SimpleString(str.c_str()); } // otherwise, run block-free code
   }
}
catch ( error_already_set e ) { PyErr_Print(); }

// close python
Py_Finalize();

// done
return 0;
```

I have not encountered serious problems with this hack, but it strikes me as woefully inelegant. Can anyone think of a better way to do this?

I have already cleared the boost.python libraries with my boss, if that offers some useful trick that eluded me.

EDIT: I should probably mention the program itself, while not my meagre testbed, must run on MS Windows.

Comment: To clarify here, are you trying to embed an interactive interpreter shell?

Answer (score 0):

What you've written is going to look superficially similar to the stock interpreter, but it won't follow the same indent/dedent and continuation rules for any but the most trivial cases.

The easiest way to embed an interactive interpreter shell is to embed a bare interpreter that runs an interactive interpreter written in pure Python, usually via the [`code`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html) module.

For that to work, you will have to hook up your line-by-line reader to the embedded `stdin` file object, but it seems like for any realistic use you're going to want that anyway. (Otherwise, what's going to happen if, e.g., the user types `input()` at the shell?)

An alternative is to set up a `pty` and run the stock interactive interpreter against that (possibly as a child process), feeding the pty's input pipe from your line reader.

Comment: This initial code is not meant to cover every usage case, and is certainly not intended to be a full interpreter; I would need to add things like line continuation support for the full program, but I do not want to do that until I am sure the hack above is the only way.

Running the stock interpreter against a pseudoterminal sounds like an excellent idea, though.

Comment: The fact that the actual program needs to run on Windows might also be a problem; not sure how that OS handles `pty`s.

Comment: @J.T.Davies: Windows doesn't have pty's. There are various different ways to fake it. When I had to do something similar years ago, I wrote almost completely separate code for Windows and everything else. IIRC, the Windows code, instead of faking out isatty, actually launched a real console app with a hidden console window as a child process and talked to the console window, or something horrible like that. But that may have only been necessary because I had to deal with Win9x, which hopefully isn't an issue nowadays…

Comment: I had another thought: IDLE has its own robust, portable wrappers for running an interactive interpreter that thinks it owns a console, but is actually talking to the IDLE GUI. I don't know how easy they are to extract from the rest of IDLE, but it may be worth a look. (I believe IPython also has similar "remoting" support, but it's being phased out in favor of the new zeromq-based design that isn't finished yet.)